# Building MongoDB C Driver in Windows

Tags: mongodb

## What I did so far

I read [the installation guide](http://api.mongodb.com/c/current/installing.html).

Installed OpenSSL library for Windows after downloading [a setup file](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Downloaded and extracted a Mongo C Driver directory from [GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver).

Installed CMake for Windows after downloading from [CMake web site](https://cmake.org/download/).

Went to `mongo-c-driver/src/libbson` and run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"` and it prints (maybe) success.

`D:\works\test\mongo-c-driver\src\libbson>cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
Current version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.4.0-dev
Previous release (from VERSION_RELEASED file): 1.3.5
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf - found
-- Looking for _set_output_format
-- Looking for _set_output_format - not found
-- Performing Test BSON_HAVE_TIMESPEC
-- Performing Test BSON_HAVE_TIMESPEC - Success
--     struct timespec found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/works/test/mongo-c-driver/src/libbson`

Executed `msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj` and prints the success.

## The problem

Went to `mongo-c-driver` and run `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" and prints errors like this.

`-- Found BSON: BSON-NOTFOUND;ws2_32

-- Found OpenSSL: optimized;D:/apps/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/ssleay32MD.lib;debug;D:/apps/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/ssleay32MDd.lib;optimized;D:/apps/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libeay32MD.lib;debug;D:/apps/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libeay32MDd.lib (found version "1.0.2h") 
-- Searching for sasl/sasl.h
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/include for SASL support)
-- Searching for libsasl2
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/lib for SASL support)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/works/test/mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".`

I looked for `sasl.h` from my disks but there is none. I also looked for it from [OpenSSL GitHub](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) but it does not have sasl.h

I downloaded and opened cyrus-sasl from [here](https://cyrusimap.org/mediawiki/index.php/Downloads#SASL_Library), but I am stuck with it. I don't know what to do with it.

How can I do the successful build of MongoDB C Driver?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the libsasl2 port to Windows is not complete.  Although I did ultimately get libsasl to compile, there was no libsasl2 produced.  It appears that SASL is used by MongoDB C Driver for Kerberos.  I don't know if they have tried to get Kerberos working with the C Driver on Windows without a port of the libsasl2 library.

I was, however, able to get the MongoDB C Driver to ultimately compile.  I initially tried to compile using subdirectories of C:\, as opposed to C:\mongo-c-driver etc., but that didn't work well, but when I compiled using the directory structure in the documentation, the compile succeeded.

To get it to compile, I disabled the SASL library in the compilation.  I don't think it will be needed unless you need to use Kerberos.  I initially had to explicitly disable SASL (perhaps because of using 64 bit) -- that can be done with `-DENABLE_SASL=no` when compiling the mongo-c-driver.

Here are the steps:

Got driver source from this page: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases (1.3.5)

Got cmake from https://cmake.org/download/

Installed cmake using the Windows installer, adding cmake to the path for all users.  I had to log out and log back in to get the path to update.

Then, I copied the mongo-c-driver-1.3.5 source to c:\mongo-c-driver-1.3.5

Then,

I used the Visual Studio MSBuild Command Prompt, started with Run As Administrator

```
C:\mongo-c-driver-1.3.5\src\libbson>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\libmongoc -G "Visual Studio 14"
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/mongo-c-driver-1.3.5/src/libbson/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/mongo-c-driver-1.3.5/src/libbson/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Turns out that the C compilers are not installed with a standard installation of Visual Studio, so I had to install C++ component of Visual Studio.  I installed C++ Common Tools, but not MFC for C++ nor XP Support.  That said it would use 3 GB of disk space (started at 39.5, ended at 37.0, so 2.5 GB used)

Once that was installed:

```
cd \mongo-c-driver-1.3.5\src\libbson
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\libmongoc -G "Visual Studio 14" .
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
cd ..\..

C:\mongo-c-driver-1.3.5>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\libmongoc -DENABLE_SSL=WINDOWS -DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\libmongoc -G "Visual Studio 14" .
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23026.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.23026.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found BSON: C:/libmongoc/lib/bson-1.0.lib;ws2_32
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing:  OPENSSL_LIBRARIES OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Searching for sasl/sasl.h
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/include for SASL support)
-- Searching for libsasl2
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/lib for SASL support)
Current version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.3.5
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/mongo-c-driver-1.3.5
```

OpenSSL was not present, so I obtained 32 bit Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.2h from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Then, I installed OpenSSL.  Changed installation directory to C:\work\OpenSSL-Win32, and I allowed the OpenSSL installer to install the binaries into the Windows system directory

Now,

```
C:\mongo-c-driver-1.3.5>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\libmongoc -DENABLE_SSL=WINDOWS -DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\libmongoc -G "Visual Studio 14" .
-- Found OpenSSL: optimized;C:/work/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/ssleay32MD.lib;debug;C:/work/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/ssleay32MDd.lib;optimized;C:/work/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/libeay32MD.lib;debug;C:/work/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/libeay32MDd.lib (found version "1.0.2h")
-- Searching for sasl/sasl.h
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/include for SASL support)
-- Searching for libsasl2
--   Not found (specify -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=C:/path/to/sasl/lib for SASL support)
Current version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.3.5
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/mongo-c-driver-1.3.5

C:\mongo-c-driver-1.3.5>

msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
(lots of output, with some yellow warnings, but no red errors)

msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

And now the mongo-c-driver has been built.  I can use it with Visual C++ to connect to my MongoDB server using ssl.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to get Embarcadero RADStudio C++ Builder to use the new mongo-c-driver.  Just copying the .dll's into the application's folder results in an abort in the bson dll.  The stack trace looks like this:

[image: Screenshot showing stack trace]

Answer (score 3):

There are two errors in that output.
- libbson must be installed and available
- mongoc is configured against cyrus sasl, in which case it must be installed and available

Both are easily fixable, and later versions of mongoc will no longer error if cyrus sasl or openssl isn't available, but will instead use the Windows native implementations. The driver can also be configured without them.
The available configuration options and values are:

```
-DENABLE_SASL=[CYRUS|SSPI|AUTO|OFF]
-DENABLE_SSL=[OPENSSL|WINDOWS|DARWIN|AUTO|OFF]
```

Unfortunately the `cmake` installation of mongoc will not automatically install the bundled libbson for you, this may be fixed in the future, but for now you need to install it seperately.

In short, to install the mongoc driver on Windows:

Download & extract mongoc (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases).
mongoc releases comes with libbson sources so no need to download them seperately.
Enter the libbson directory, "src/libbson" and then:

```
cd c:/path/to/mongoc/
cd src/libbson

# Configure and install libbson
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/mongoc
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj # Installs libbson

cd ../.. # Go back to the root folder of the release sources

# Configure and install mongoc
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=c:/mongoc \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=c:/mongoc/lib/cmake \
    -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP:BOOL=OFF \
    -DENABLE_SSL=WINDOWS \ # Use Windows Native TLS, rather then OpenSSL
    -DENABLE_SASL=SSPI # Use Windows Native SSPI, rather then Cyrus SASL
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

Comment: While this works (thank you!), keep in mind that it defaults to debug configuration... To build other configs (available are: `Debug`, `Release`, `MinSizeRel` and `RelWithDebInfo`) add a corresponding argument to msbuild commands, e.g. `msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release`, `msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release`

Answer (score 1):

With a current **Visual Studio** you can just open the project, build all and get your DLLs.

- I used Community 2019
- Make sure the *Desktop development with C++* workload is installed, it includes *CMake* support
- Choose *Open*, *CMake*, then select *CMakeLists.txt* from the root of the extracted source archive

Now you are already ready to "build all", but since the default debug build is not recommended, you should open CMake settings, use the green "+" button and select *x86-Release* (or *x64*, if required).

---

For **Delphi** users: the default DLL filenames are without the required "lib" prefix (libmongoc-1.0.dll), so edit the `BSON_OUTPUT_BASENAME` and `MONGOC_OUTPUT_BASENAME` variables accordingly.

Another hint: the Delphi installation contains the files in 2 places: *bin & Redist\win32, bin64 & Redist\win64* - good luck!

Answer (score -1):

1.17.0-rc0 x86 release drivers

https://gofile.io/d/0wJ4R4