# MongoDB Connection Error

Tags: mongodb, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

When i try to connect to mongodb (after setting Database, Username, Password, Server and Port values) with FDConnection i get `[FireDAC][Phys][Mongo]The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported..` error.

If I set UseSSL option to True and try again this time I get `[FireDAC][Phys][Mongo]SSL is not enabled in this build of mongo-c-driver..` error.

In the same computer I can connect to MongoDB with MongoBooster (with Basic Authentication)

Answer (score 2):

### SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism

Upgrade to the latest [**mongo-c-driver**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver) (or at least version 1.1.0) because the one you use does not support [**SCRAM-SHA-1**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/) authentication mechanism (which is what the driver exception says). And since it was introduced and became default authentication mechanism in MongoDB 3.0, you must be using old driver against new DBMS.

### MONGODB-CR authentication mechanism

Upgrade to the latest [**mongo-c-driver**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver) (or at least version 1.1.0) for reason desribed above. Since [**MONGODB-CR**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-cr/) is no longer default authentication mechanism, you need to explicitly specify it by setting [**authMechanism**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authMechanism) to [**MONGODB-CR**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-cr/).

So if you want basic authentication, you need to specify this in the [**MongoAdvanced**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_MongoDB_Database_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters) parameter:

```
...
FDConnection1.Params.Add('MongoAdvanced=authMechanism=MONGODB-CR');
FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

### Evidence about outdated driver

Following links point to corresponding source code lines where you can find evidence about your outdated driver:

- [**version 1.0.2**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.0.2/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1747) - *The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported* message will be returned due to missing **SCRAM-SHA-1** mechanism.
- [**version 1.1.0**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.1.0/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1877) - no such message will be shown, because **SCRAM-SHA-1** mechanism exists.
- [**version 1.6.3**](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.6.3/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1119) - in current version, the message sounds *Unknown authentication mechanism*.

So, that message *The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported* you can get with driver version older than 1.1.0. Build the driver from the latest stable source and set the library path to the [**VendorLib**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.TFDPhysDriverLink.VendorLib) property of your physical driver link component.

Something like this (don't be confused by the version in the library name, authors keep it outdated, but it may change in the future):

```
FDPhysMongoDriverLink1.VendorLib := 'C:\PathToDriver\libmongoc-1.0.dll';
```

Comment: Regarding to [link in mogoc.org](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html) I've builded mongodb drivers and under "C:\mongo-c-driver\bin" directory 4 dll(s) created. Copied them manually under my exe and run application `[FireDAC][Phys][Mongo]The authentication mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" is not supported..`error coming still. If I try your `params.add`suggestion `[FireDAC][Phys][Mongo]Failed to authenticate credentials.` error coming :(

Comment: Have you properly updated `VendorLib` property of your `TFDPhysMongoDriverLink`?

Comment: Now i tried to set VendorLib with my existing old file because there are only 4 dlls (concrt140, libbson-1.0, msvcp140, vcruntime140) under `C:\mongo-c-driver\bin`and same error messages continue to come.

Comment: We are talking about libmongoc-1.0.dll library (don't be confused by the version). Path to that library you must set to the `VendorLib` property. That you are not using recent driver can be easily proven, [version 1.0.2](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.0.2/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1747) no SCRAM-SHA-1 (hence the message), [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/1.1.0/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1877) added SCRAM-SHA-1 (would lead to no such message),...

Comment: ...[current version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/src/mongoc/mongoc-cluster.c#L1327) message is now "Unknown authentication mechanism...", instead of "The authentication mechanism is not supported.". So you must be using version below 1.1.0 where SCRAM-SHA-1 was not yet recognized. As for your build, it seems that you built only libbson.

Comment: Sorry for mistake I builded and installed only libbson not mongo-c-driver. When I try to build mongo-c-driver regarding to [link ](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html) after running `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" \ "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-c-driver" \ "-DBSON_ROOT_DIR=C:\mongo-c-driver"`` command I get following error: `CMake Error: The source directory "/" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.` I tried to copy CMakeLists.txt file from libbson to mongo-c-driver directory or root directory but still get same error.

Comment: Sorry, but this is out of context of this question. You need to use a recent driver, that's for sure. If you need help about building the driver, ask a new question, please.

Comment: See this answer for easy build and Delphi use instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078230/1855801